# 'onsubmit' not running javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been trying to figure this out for the last hour or so to no avail. I can't even get it to run.

```
<form action='Summary2.php' method='post' id='summary2Form' onsubmit='return validateSummaryForm(this);'>
    <table  id='jobTable' align='center'>
        <tr>
            <div name='jobDiv'>
                <td>
                    <p><font size='4'>Select Job Name: </font></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="jobNameSelect" name="jobNameSelect">
                        <?php
                            print '<option></option>';
                            foreach($jobNumArray as $jobNum) {
                                print '<option>'.$jobNum.'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div type="submit" id="summaryNext">
                    <input type="submit" id="summaryNext">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

```js
function validateSummaryForm(test) {
    var e = document.getElementById(test.id);
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(strUser);
    if(strUser == ""){
        $("Table").effect("shake");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

The above html will not even run the javascript function, which is in an external file. My Import statement are below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

the `../jQuery.js` is where the javascript function is held. This file also has a lot of jQuery, which all works in different webpages. The javascript function is simply at the end of the jQuery. I took out mostly all of the PHP from the code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As you're using the `effect()` method, which is part of jQueryUI, you need to include your `jQuery.js` script *after* `jquery-ui.min.js`

Comment: I did that, however it still didn't work. @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using the `effect()` method, which is part of jQueryUI, you need to include your `jQuery.js` script *after* `jquery-ui.min.js`. Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

I would also strongly suggest you rename the `jQuery.js` file to something else, as it's a very misleading name.

Your validation logic is also flawed; `e.options[e.selectedIndex]` will be causing an error at least. Assuming you're trying to ensure an `option` has been selected you can just check the `val()` of the parent `select`. As you're using jQuery it would also be better practice to use it to attach your event handlers instead of outdate `on*` attributes:

```
<form action='Summary2.php' method='post' id='summary2Form'>
```

```js
$('#summary2Form').submit(function(e) {
    if ($('#jobNameSelect').val() == '') {
        $("table").effect("shake");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

Finally, the HTML. `div` elements do not have a `type` attribute and you're giving it the same `id` as the `input`. `id` attributes must be unique within the document otherwise your HTML will be invalid.

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" id="summaryNext">
</div>
```

Also, the `<div name='jobDiv'>` cannot be a direct child of a `tr`, it need to go outside the `table`, or inside a `td`, and the `name` attribute should be removed as it too is invalid on a `div`.

For future reference you can quickly diagnose errors like this by checking the developer tools console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: This Worked! However, would you mind explaining why the onsubmit element in my html form tag wouldnt even run the javascript at all? I put an alert in so I could test if it even ran, to no avail.

Comment: Most likely because there were other JS errors in the page which prevented further execution.